# Docker Compose : invalid from flag value builder:

Tags: docker

Hello I'm trying to make a dockercompose, but I have the following error:

> invalid from flag value builder: pull access denied for builder,
>   repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied:
>   requested access to the resource is denied

I can't imagine where I might be missing

my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    container_name: "db"
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    container_name: "pgadmin4"
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: emasa@emasa.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin

  api:
    image: server_emasa
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}"
volumes:
  db_data:
```

my DockerFile:

```
 FROM node as builder
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/dist ./dist
COPY ormconfig.docker.json ./ormconfig.json
COPY .env . 
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn run build
COPY back-end/ ./
EXPOSE 4000
```

and my env file:

```
SERVER_PORT = 4000
DB_HOST = 0.0.0.0
DB_PORT = 5432
DB_USER = spirit
DB_PASS = emasa
DB_NAME = emasa_base
```

my json orm config:

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "${DB_HOST}",
  "port": "${DB_PORT}",
  "username": "${DB_USER}",
  "password": "${DB_PASS}",
  "database": "${DB_NAME}",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
  "migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
  "subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `COPY` you are able to use `--from` to refer to some previous build stage or to some external image. Since `builder` is your current build stage Docker is thinking that your `--from=builder` refers to some external image and therefore gives you that error. Check again if your Dockerfile is correct.

---

Let's start with the basics. Try:

```
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR usr/app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn run build
EXPOSE 4000
```

Comment: I don't know if it's correct, but I basically tried to follow a tutorial, I don't know how to solve it

Comment: which tutorial? Is this a node.js app?

Comment: yes is a nodejs app with typescript and typeorm and graphql

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7L78RGdXHc i try with this config

Comment: You can see [here](https://gist.github.com/miko1991/9504b0866e495e2959c154dabb5edefa) that it has 2 build stages.

Comment: but I don't have a client at the moment so I didn't put

I was a little confused on how to solve this now

Comment: can u help me with this?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the simplest Dockerfile. Try it and give me feedback. If it works, we can try to optimize it.

Comment: @ Stefan Golubović this work, can you help me optimize?

Comment: but for some reason my api is not running:

my container:

 Restarting (0) 25 seconds ago

and not got my console .log on start server

Comment: I'm going to need some logs. What is logged when you do `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose logs api`?

Comment: basically shows my pgadmin container and postgres container logs but not my server node

Comment: an example:
don't show mine
console.log (` Server ready at http: // localhost: 4000 $ {server.graphqlPath}`)

Comment: I cannot help you if you can't tell me why the server didn't start.